# Phonegap application crashes while trying to access one page which is not in the same directory

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I have two links in an application the fist one as below and it's working fine:-

```
<a href="login.html"><img src="images/en.png" width="30" height="30" >English</a>
```

The second one is as below with the error `There was a network error. (file:///android_asset/www/login.html)` :-

```
<a href="../login.html"><img src="images/en.png" width="30" height="30" >English</a>
```

which means that the application crashes while trying to access html file which is not located in the same directory. Any Idea Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path should be set as absolute path as below:-

```
file:///android_asset/www/login.html
```

But this requires to set a condition case for the used platform as the above will not work with iOS. To short it cut and only if you are developing a small application, drop your files in one location and set a relative path.

Another Advice, I found that XDK is better than Phonegap. Intel is rock!

Thanks!